# Can I use MPMediaQuery to get the year of a song?

Tags: ios, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I've been reading the iOS iPod library documentation, trying to figure out if there is a way to fecth or filter song and/or albums by the year of publication.

The MPMediaItem Class reference states that you can use:

```
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPlayCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertySkipCount;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyRating;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyLastPlayedDate;
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyUserGroupin;
```

But it doesn't mention year of publication at all.

Answer (score 3):

try MPMediaItemPropertyReleaseDate